# find rows in database with 2 or more values of a column in common

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called articletag for a blog database that says which article has which tag:

```
Art_Id  Tag_id
       1    3
       2    3
       3    3
       4    3
       1    1
       3    1
       4    1
       2    2
       5    5
```

another way to see this data is:

```
1, "blog", "first"
2, "blog", "second"
3, "blog", "first"
4, "blog", "first"
5, "seaside"
```

Tag_id 3 = 'blog' Tag_id 1 = 'first' Tag_id 5 = 'seaside' Tag_id 2 = 'second'

I am specifically looking for any articles with 2 or more words in common among EVERY article in the database and EVERY word tag (these tags are unique, btw)
Looking at the denormalized example above the answer should be 1,3,4, as articles with 2 or more words in common. Those 3 articles clearly share "blog" and "first."
The output should be

art_id

1
   3
   4

I have been trying for hours to get this right. The best I came up with was finding which tag_id shows up 2 or more times using:

```
Select a.* 
from articletag a 
  join (
    select t.tag_id 
    from articletag t 
    group by t.tag_id 
    having count(*) >=2 
  ) b on b.tag_id = a.tag_id
```

But what I really want is which Article_id's have 2 or more words in common
Can anyone please help?

Comment: make it more clear and add expected output

Comment: should 1,3,4   and not 1,2,4  lloking to your sample

Comment: sorry its getting late. you are are right scaisEdge

Comment: Jay I have expected output given as scaisEdge saw himself, as 1,3,4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @x table (art_id int, tag_id int)
insert into @x values 
(1,    3),
(2,    3),
(3,    3),
(4,    3),
(1,    1),
(3,    1),
(4,    1),
(2,    2),
(5,    5)

select distinct art_id from (
    select [x1].art_id,
           COUNT(*) over (partition by [x1].art_id,[x2].art_id) [cnt] 
    from @x [x1] join @x [x2]
    on [x1].tag_id = [x2].tag_id and [x1].art_id <> [x2].art_id
) a where cnt > 1
```

Comment: @Femke This may not be what you need, if you also need to know the actual article pairs which have tags in common.

Comment: hmm but its not translating to my table.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Tim i only need the article id, actually, thank you. and Michal's answer is great except it doesn't work on my two column table. i'm trying to tweak it. 5 hours on this one problem is too much. i should go to bed

Comment: Idk Michal I'm so fried. All i can tell you is that its not good for me to have to declare a new table with 3 columns. I have to find something that works on the two column table that is at the beginning of my question. Your code is perfect, I really think I am just brain dead now

Comment: @Femke Can there be more than 2 tags per article? From your example looks like there can be at most 2 tags.

Comment: acutally that is just incidental from the example, there can be n tags per article

Comment: @MichałTurczyn  this is incredible thank you.. and thank you for taking so much time for my issue. I appreciate this greatly

Answer (score 2):

We can try doing a self join here:

```
SELECT t1.Art_id, t2.Art_id
FROM articletag t1
INNER JOIN articletag t2
    ON t2.Art_id > t1.Art_id AND
       t1.Tag_id = t2.Tag_id
GROUP BY
    t1.Art_id, t2.Art_id
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT t1.Tag_id) >= 2;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that I am seeing 1-3, 1-4, and 3-4 as being the articles which have two or more tags in common.

Comment: thank you, this seems close, but i only have one set of article id's so i'm not sure why there are two columns. The values are correct though if i can just figure out how to reduce it to simply

Comment: What is the output you actually want?  Just a list of numbers?

Comment: Thank you , this seems close, but sorry, I don't get why there are two columns with same name? also an article id is just '1' or '2' not '1-3'.

Comment: Sorry Tim, just one column of numbers with art_id name and whatever art_ids match the spec

Comment: `with art_id name and whatever art_ids match the spec` <-- what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `cte` to find the `Art_Id`s which have same combination

```
;with cte as
(
    select Tag_id
    from table
    group by Tag_id
    having count(*) >= 2
)

select t.Art_Id 
from cte c inner join table t 
        on t.Tag_id = c.Tag_id
group by t.Art_Id 
having count(*) = (select count(1) from cte)
```